# CSS Brace Styles

Tags: css, coding-style, naming-conventions

I'm unable to figure how the standard (or just *popular*) brace style names apply to CSS. Here're all the brace styles:

```css
/* one - pico? */
selector { property: value; 
           property: value; }

/* two - pico extra */
selector { 
    property: value; /* Start Properties on Newline */
    property: value; }

/* three - horstmann? */
selector 
{ property: value;
  property: value;
}

/* four - GNU? */
selector 
{ 
    property: value; /* Start Properties on Newline */
    property: value;
}​

/* five - GNU Saver */
selector { property: value;
           property: value;
}

/* six - CSS Default */
selector { 
    property: value; /* Start Properties on Newline */
    property: value;
}

/* seven - Braces Aligned */
selector { property: value;
           property: value;
         }

/* eight - Banner? */
selector {
    property: value; /* Start Properties on Newline */
    property: value;
    }
```

Can someone please name each brace style for me?

Many thanks!

Comment: You have to be careful with those brace styles - get it wrong and evil pixies will come and eat your brain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say three is Horstmann.

Pico as it is, but the opening brace starts on a newline.

Banner would be:

```css
selector {
    property: value;
    property: value;
    }
```

The rest of your guesses seem correct.

I took most of these from [Indent style on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) :)

Comment: I've named all 8, can you help improve them if you can. :)

Comment: Okay thanks. Can you suggest better names for 'Pico Extra' and 'GNU Saver' :P

Comment: I'm not sure there is a 'named' style for every one you've got there - I did find this, http://gulati.info/2010/01/different-brace-styles-in-php, which helps highlight the differences, specifically between GNU and Horstmann.

Comment: It seems unclear whether opening braces starting on newlines are part of the Pico style. [ProCSSor](http://procssor.com) shows the same Pico style as in the question. Hmmm...

Answer (score 2):

I think you named the most popular indent styles yourself. I personally, prefer:

```
.class {
  property: value;
}
```

Comment: I've named all the 8, please help improve if you can.

Answer (score 2):

four should be Allman Style

it's my favorite

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes write css with the starting- and ending brace on the same line.
Often used like:
`.foo {width:100%;height:550px;}`

How would this be named?

`/* Nine - Almost-optimized(?) */

selector { property: value; property: value; }`